# Determining whether compiling on Windows or other system

Tags: c, include, cross-platform, c-preprocessor, platform-specific

I'm currently developing a cross-platform **C** application.
Is there any compiler macro which is defined only during compilation on Windows, so I can `#ifdef` some Windows specific #includes?

Typical example is selecting between WinSock and Berkeley sockets headers:

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
   #include <winsock.h>    
#else
   #include <sys/socket.h>
   #include <netinet/in.h>
   #include <sys/un.h>
   #include <arpa/inet.h>
   #include <netdb.h>
#endif
```

So the thing I'm looking for is something like that **_WINDOWS** macro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your best bet is to use

```
_WIN32
```

It is [guaranteed to be defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.100).aspx) when compiling for a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows platform using the Visual C++ compiler.  I would expect other compilers for Windows to define it as well (the Intel C++ compiler defines it, as does the MinGW gcc).

Comment: And what in case of 64-bit Windows? I presume _WIN32 is defined only on 32 bit systems, right?

Comment: The 32 is really there to separate it from ancient 16-bit versions of Windows. Removing that definition in Win64 would've broken too much stuff, so it was less hassle to leave it in.

Answer (score 3):

Use `_WIN32`.

Reference:

- [Microsoft C++ Predefined Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [GCC Predefined Macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html)
- [How to get predefined macros for OS X](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2005/qa1424.html) (or just check for `__APPLE__`)

Answer (score 2):

```
_WIN32
```

Defined for applications for Win32 and Win64. Always defined.

```
_WIN64
```

Defined for applications for Win64.

Source : [Lists the predefined ANSI C and Microsoft C++ implementation macros.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)